# Visual C++ 2010 default settings

Tags: visual-c++, default, projects-and-solutions

Can I get the default settings for Visual C++ 2010? I messed up a bit when I tried to get DarkGDK to work with it. I need to know what is the default "Include Directories", "Library Directories", "Additional Dependencies", and lastly "Ignore Specific Default Libraries". Thanks.

Comment: At this point, it's probably easiest to just create a new project, move all your source files, and "Add Existing File to Project".

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried it already, I just need to know those 4 things.

Answer (score 0):

What settings did the brand new project have in those four fields?

If those weren't right, time to run "Repair Installation" from control panel or the Visual Studio Help menu.

---

My "Additional Dependencies" is "kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;comctl32.lib;ole32.lib;shell32.lib;winmm.lib", but whether that's applicable to you or not depends on the project type.

Executable Directories is "$(VCInstallDir)bin;$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;$(WindowsSdkDir)bin;$(VSInstallDir)Common7\Tools\bin;$(VSInstallDir)Common7\tools;$(VSInstallDir)Common7\ide;$(ProgramFiles)\HTML Help Workshop;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\bin;$(MSBuildToolsPath32);$(VSInstallDir);$(SystemRoot)\SysWow64;$(FxCopDir);$(PATH);"

Include Directories is "$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;"

Library Directories is "$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib"

Ignore Specific Default Libraries is blank.

Comment: In "Include Directories" it says ; $(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include; 

In "Library Directories" is says "$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\"

The next four are blank.